# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a MVC application. I am passing some data between views like this:

```
public ActionResult AddGroup(AddGroupViewModel model)
        {
            var entities = new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1();
            var model1 = new AddGroupViewModel();
            model1.Subjects = entities.Subjects.ToList();
            model1.Users = entities.Users.ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var subj = entities.Subjects
                    .Where(b => b.name == model.subject_name)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
                int id = subj.class_id;
                return RedirectToAction("AddGroupsQty", "Account", new { qty = model.qty, subject_id = id});
            }
            return View(model1);
        }
```

And:

```
public ActionResult AddGroupsQty(int qty, int id)
{
    ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1 entities = new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1();

    var model = new AddGroupsQtyViewModel();
    model.subject_id = id;
    model.qty = qty;
    ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1 entities1=new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1();
    var subj = entities1.Subjects
            .Where(b => b.class_id == model.subject_id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    model.subject_name = subj.name;
    return View(model);
}
```

But unfortunately, I get this error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AddGroupsQty(Int32, Int32)' in
>   'ClassDeclarationsThsesis.Controllers.AccountController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter. Nazwa parametru: parameters
>   [image]
>   How do I go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your action method `AddGroupsQty` has 2 parameters, `qty` and `id`, But when you do the redirect,your querystring does not have the id one! Instead it has one called `subject_id`

To fix the error, change your route value item from `subject_id` to `id`

```
return RedirectToAction("AddGroupsQty", "Account", new { qty = model.qty, id = id});
```

Or you can change the `AddGroupsQty` action method parameter from `id` to `subject_id` (make sure to check all other places and fix the querystring/route values as needed)